# Xamarin change full screen color

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, screen, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a scanner app build in Xamarin for Android and IOS.
When the scanner succeed I want to show a green screen of 0,5 seconds.
And when it fails I want to show a red screen.

But I can't find any code that allows me to create that screen.

I hope anyone here can push me in the right direction.

Comment: every View has a backgroundcolor property - have you tried that?

Comment: Maby it sounds stupid, but I think that I don't have a viewable view. I've downloaded a barcodescan project to get started with learning Xamarin and I do only have a button on it, what is created in the c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have a callback function when scanner succeed or fails.
In the callback function you can use `BackgroundColor = Color.Red;` to change the background.

Every page have the `BackgroundColor` property. For example I created a bottom by code and click the button to change the page background:

```
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var page1 = new ContentPage();
            Button changeBgBt = new Button { Text = "change backgroud color", WidthRequest = 100, HeightRequest = 50, VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            changeBgBt.Clicked += ChangeBgBt_Clicked;
            var content = new StackLayout();
            content.Children.Add(changeBgBt);
            page1.Content = content;
            MainPage = page1;
        }

        private void ChangeBgBt_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainPage.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        }
```